# How I can change the order of two column in R?

Tags: r, database

How I can swap 2 colmn of a data set in R? for example I have

```
 1  56
 2   43
 3   42
 4   32
```

and I want to have

```
   56    1
    43   2
    42   3
    32   4
```

Comment: Just do `df1[ncol(df1):1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do the reverse sequence (generalized)

```
df2 <- df1[ncol(df1):1]
```

or for a two column, it is

```
df1[2:1]
```

---

If the OP wants to select only a particular column

```
df2 <- df1[c(6, 1:5)]
```

---

With `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
        select(6, everything())
```

Comment: I have 6 column and I want to bring the last one as a first column

Comment: @user9272398  The first option would get it right or if you want to only take the last column first `df1[c(6, 1:5)]`

Comment: where I should write the name of dataset?

Comment: @user9272398  Lets say you read the dataset in `R` `df1 <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")` and here the code is working on that identifier

Comment: oh yes. when I write the data set to a txt file, there is a row in the begging before first column, do you know how I can remove it? I tried data[,-0] but it is not working. it is number of rows in " ".

Comment: @user9272398  If you are using `write.table`, `write.csv`, you can specify `row.names = FALSE`

Comment: thank you my last question for you : do you know if I can add this new column to data set : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 ... basically one 1 and 3 zero

Comment: @user9272398  You can assign new column `df1$newColumn <- c(1, 0, 0, ....)` if i understand

Comment: new column is not 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 it is 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 . . .  (one 1 then three 0  , one 1 then three 0 , ...)

Comment: @user9272398  You need `rep` i.e. `rep(rep(c(1, 0), c(1, 3)), length.out = nrow(df1))`

Comment: one more question: I have a column with false and true entries how I can change it to 0 and 1?

Comment: @user9272398  Just do `as.integer(df1$columnName)` or `+(df1$columnName)`

Comment: do I need a package?

Comment: @user9272398  No, it is `base R`

Comment: I get error: operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @user9272398  Do you have a `matrix` in that case `df1[, columnName]` where `columnName <- "stringName"`

Comment: it changed to 1 and 2 not 1 and 0

Comment: @user9272398  Looks like you have a `factor` column.  What is the result of `as.logical(df1[, columnName])`?  Do you have as `TRUE/FALSE` or `True/False`.  The upper case format is the one used in `R` for logical vector.   If it is the second one, try `as.integer(df1[, columnName] == "True")`

Comment: @user9272398  In that case, it is `as.integer(df1[, columnName] == "yes")`

Comment: `df[2:1]` notation is nice in two-column dataframes, but not generalizable; i.e., if one has a three-column dataframe, `df[2:1]` removes the 3rd column. Hence, maybe, changing the positions in `c(...)` generalizable a little more.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an arbitary order if you would like.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  select(col3,col4,col2,col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(c1 = 1:4, c2 = c(56, 43, 42, 32))
df
#  c1 c2
#1  1 56
#2  2 43
#3  3 42
#4  4 32

df[c(2,1)]
#  c2 c1
#1 56  1
#2 43  2
#3 42  3
#4 32  4
```

You can swap by changing the locations within `c` (combine):

```
df <- data.frame(c1=1:4, c2=c(56,43,42,32), c3=c(12,13,14,15));df
#  c1 c2 c3
#1  1 56 12
#2  2 43 13
#3  3 42 14
#4  4 32 15

df[c(3,1,2)]
#  c3 c1 c2
#1 12  1 56
#2 13  2 43
#3 14  3 42
#4 15  4 32
```